# pgAdmin does not show the message error at the Process Watcher

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I've been had hard times trying to fix this problem, the message error log does not appear. I've tried to reinstall to a old version, changing configuration that I've found here, changed location, changed conf file to message and nothing helped. So I'd like to know if someone can help me.
Thank you

[enter image description here][image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, not sure what's happening. But the work around is by opening the physical log here: C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\sessions\process_logs

When the pop up dialog still open, a temporary folder will be created and inside the folder you will get some files, then open the "err" file, this is where you can see the detail

[pgadmin error process log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Mva.png)

Comment: I just got this information, the problem is fixed and will be released on 28 January 2020. https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/6140